# Binding between two custom dependencyobjects

Tags: wpf, data-binding

i have a custom dependecyobject created in xaml and i would like to bind the whole instance of it to a property of another custom dependecyobject. all that is happening inside a control.
As example something like this

```
class row : dependencyobject
{
   // this is a dp property
   public static readonly dependencyproperty widthproperty = dependencyproperty.register...
}

class cell : dependencyobject
{

   public static readonly dependencyproperty dataproperty = dependencyproperty.register....
}

class customGridView:Control
{
  List<Row>Rows { get;set;}
  List<Cell> Cells { get;set;}
}
```

and now i would like to bind an instance of a row to cell.data property, also something like this:

```
<customGridView>
 <row x:name:row1 width=200/> (this is a class that derives for dependencyobject)
 <row .../>
 <cell data={Binding ElementName=row1}/> (this is another class that derives from dependencyobj and tries to bind to entire instance of row class)
 <cell ..../>
 <cell ..../>
</customGridView/>
```

any help?

as desired this is the dp property of cell.data:

```
 public Row Data
    {
        get { return (Row)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ColumnName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty=
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(Row), typeof(Cell), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I got your Problem do it like this

```
  <cell.data>
    <x:Reference Name="row1"/>
  </cell.data>
```

Comment: i dont want to use resources, i define the objects and initialize them in xaml without putting them into window.resources :) and you havent understood my question. its not hard to understand, smiles

Comment: for that you will have to show more of your code , so that we can know how exactly things going.

Comment: its easy, there is not much code to show anyway. I have a custom control that exploses properties whos types are classes that derivate from a dependecyobect.. futhermore each class contains different properties and i would like to do the binding among them as shown in question above :)

Comment: nope thats not my problem, i will try to edit my question furthermore to provide you with more infos

Comment: rows and cells are not derivering from FrameworkElement or a Control.. they are just pure DependencyObjects

Comment: for that Data of Cell must be of Type Row for Binding to Work.

Comment: It is.. its all matching the same type and still i get a bindingexpression error telling me the dataitem = null :-( 
i am wondering if i am binding correctly with ElementName=row1? Is that line of code ok?

Comment: This is the Error Message "Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element"

Comment: please show the wrapper property of the both of your dependency properties of class row and cell.

Comment: there are no both, just on on cell side, since cell.data wants to recieve the completely row instance.. i will edit the question to let you know how my property looks like

Comment: it works.. dude your great!! help me understand why doesnt binding work in such case? and why using x:Reference? what is x:reference anyway?

Comment: i am getting a INameResolver service exception, how do i get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how, for instance, `Grid` and `RowDefinition` are implemented :

- Your `Row` and `Cell` classes must inherit from [FrameworkContentElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkcontentelement.aspx) which inherits from `DependencyObject` and defines the `Name` property, allowing your instances to be registered in the appropriate [INameScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.inamescope.aspx) to later be found.
- You somewhat need to link these instances to the [logical tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx) as the binding in `Cell` relies on it to find 'row1'. See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2008/05/23/of-logical-and-visual-trees-in-wpf.aspx) for further explanations.

Comment: i tried it out, and i got another exception. something with defered content initialization.. however, since i figured out that inamescope is an desintime error, i dont mind about it. building and executing the app works fine :)

Comment: actually i would like to get rid of that INameScope Exception and its not working with FrameworkContentElement. Can you help me out?